# How to get a Background color on a Kivy Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, kivy

I am using Kivy to make an app, and I'm trying to display a label. Here's my main code

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class storageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kvfile

class LoginPage(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kvfile = Builder.load_file('storage.kv')


storageApp().run()
```

Here's my .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    current: 'login'
    LoginPage:

<LoginPage>:
    name: 'login'
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Welcome to the secret app!'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 0.95}
            background_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
```

And I get the following output on my screen

[image: screen]

The color of the label is still black. However, when Ichange the `Label` to `Button` it seems to work.

[image]

This seems very odd. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The Label doesn't have a background colour property. If you want a background, draw one:

```
<KvBackgroundRule>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```